# How to add a placeholder attribute to a Matrix cell in a SafeCracker form

Tags: matrix, safecracker, javascript

I'd like to add a placeholder attribute to a textarea Matrix cell in a SafeCracker form (so I can add some placeholder text to the field that says, 'Add your feedback here...'), and I'm using EE 2.5.5 and Matrix 2.5.6.

I don't want to hack any of the Matrix files to do this, so was hoping someone might have used a JavaScript solution for this previously and be able to share the code.

Here's the front-end output for this particular Matrix cell, and the entire Matrix field is surrounded by a div with an ID of cf_amendment_details. Thanks for any help with this.

```
<td class="matrix matrix-last matrix-text"><textarea class="matrix-textarea" name="cf_amendment_details[row_new_0][col_id_19]" rows="1" dir="ltr"></textarea></td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the JavaScript I've ended up using to add a placeholder to the first row of the Matrix cell:

```
$('#cf_amendment_details').find('.matrix-textarea').attr('placeholder', 'Add your feedback here');
```

Couldn't get it working for every row, due to how the rows are added on-the-fly, but this will be fine.